Mobility of salts on unbonded bare silica HILIC column
I have two chemical compounds that I put on cells, to see if they can diffuse into the cytosol. The compounds are similar in structure, but contain a key modification that alter the polarity completely. After the cells are incubated, they are washed with PBS several times to remove excess compound. PBS is used not to rupture the cells prematurely. The goal here is just to see compound that actually went into the cell, not something that was there from the beginning in the stimulation phase.
The two compounds I test are different in polarity. The first one has good retention on RP18 and therefore residual PBS salt is not a problem to sperate off and divert into waste before the analysis of the actual compound.
The second compound is so polar that it requires a hilic phase for proper retention. The manufacturer describes the hilic phase as bare unbounded silica.
I analyse in LCMS the cell lysates after protein precipitation and centrifugation. The composition of this sample is 2 parts methanol and 1 part PBS. When I inject the sample that contains the lysate which was incubated with the polar compound, I am wondering if the salts from the PBS and the lysate are mobile on the silica if enough water is present? In my gradient I go up from 10 percent water in ACN to 100 percent water both with 10 mM NH4Fa in 15 min, staying for 4 min at 100 % (NH4Fa itself is recommended by the manufacturer which itself is a salt) I am asking this question, because from normal phase separation from purification in chemical synthesis we know, that salts stick very strongly to silica and maybe never come off it. However, in an analytical context maybe the bare silica has properties, that change this behavior?
I am also wondering if anyone would have experience with the retention time behaviour of PBS on hilic phases (so, that I can divert it as well). My goal is obviously to not let not volatile salts clog the ESI source of the instrument and make sure that the column is not loading up immobile salt deposition, while I can circumvent ion suppression of my compound by PBS. Any experience on this is highly appreciated.

Clearly mention you exact mobile phase, and gradient program in a table. If permitted, can you mention the name of compounds 1 and 2?

I added additional info on the gradient. The polar compound is a structure that contains multiple phosphonate groups and this is the only compound of interest here because the other one can be analysed by RP18.

The OP asks about phosphate-buffered saline solution and its potential retention on bare silica column under the gradient conditions provided as follows:

10 percent water in ACN to 100 percent water both with 10 mM NH4Fa in
15 min, staying at 4 min at 100 %

Yes, your concern LC-MS is valid in the sense that even inorganic ions can retain on bare silica in hydrophilic interaction liquid chromatography mode. And we do not want phosphate ions to reach the mass spectrometer. Now the term bare silica is deceptive, even if the manufacturer calls it bare silica. All "silicas" are different, in the HPLC sense due to their physicochemical properties.
See this paper for example: Takayama, Nobuyuki, Lee Wah Lim, and Toyohide Takeuchi. "Retention behavior of inorganic anions in hydrophilic interaction chromatography." Analytical Sciences 33.5 (2017): 619-623.
Even here most inorganic ions showed retention at higher ACN concentration using bonded phases. For example, in this study they show the effect of typical UV-active inorganic ions (phosphate excluded because it does not absorb UV).
Another issue is you start with 90% ACN in the beginning. This can virtually precipitate phosphate ion (this is a close range where phosphate becomes insoluble in ACN). In short, if possible switch to a simpler UV-method for HILIC in order to use your analyte X with phosphonate groups. Alternatively, find by alternative detection methods, where your analyte elutes, and use that window that goes the MS, the rest should can go to the waste.
Your gradient is too wide. I will not recommend going to 100% water. HILIC mode is notoriously slow to equilibrate and your retention times will vary here and there. Try 90-to-60 ACN at the most.

I agree, the gradient is maybe in need for optimization. I did a quick shot for a series of samples and going to 100 % was chosen because I was not yet sure when to expect the compound and wanted to ensure full cleanup between runs. However, maybe going just to 50 till 80 as max endpoint may improve separation between background salts and analyte of interest. It is maybe best to go after this gradient to a maximal value of water in a step after the gradient or in a different run. Do you say going tom 100% water will significantly increase equibrilation time in comparison to e.g. 90%?

Even with 100% at gradient end I observed same retention time for the compound after 15 min postrun. I can not go to alternative means of detection like UV, ELSD etc. because the concentration is quite low in the cell lysate. Without HRMS you would have no chance to identity it reliabi. To define two diverter positions to waste before and after the analyte would be indeed an option.

If you are observing that 100% water is not affecting retention, then the mechanism is not HILIC. Silica cannot equilibrate that fast.

I tested going from 90% organic phase to 40 % organic phase. It seems like the retention increases little bit, but it is in the same region than the 100% runs. I am more concerned about the bad response in -ESI on QTOF. Could this be related to too high Formate concentration? Booth phases had pH 3, but the ACN phase took considerably more formic acid to reach this value. I just red, that booth pH values are determined before mixing acn with the buffer. Could this a reason for weak response?

Phosphonate are troublesome compounds because they can chelate with metallic components in the HPLC/MS. Secondly, one should never measure the pH of organic solvents. It is not defined. pH is only defined for aqueous system. Just add the same amount of formic acid in organic and aqueous phase. You might have added a lot of acid.

agreed. I followed the instructions of a manufacturer guide, but it makes sense to just measure the buffer. This probably led to an increase from inded 20 mM Formate to +500.

The manufacturer mentioned to measure the pH of ACN and formic acid solution? This would be near impossible.

Maybe it was my false understanding: https://www.restek.com/videos/buffer-choices-for-hilic

Yes, the presenter does not suggest to measure the pH of organic solvents but he is not clear either. It is supposed to be a short video anyway. He emphasizes constant ionic strength for lines A and B. Simply, adjust the pH of the aqueous solvent, measure the masses, and amount of acid you added, do the same of the ACN. The ACN bottle should contain some water.

I found a resource on mixing hilic buffers. There are multiple approaches on this, an pH can also measured in organic system, but usually our pH meters are calibrated to aqueous standards: https://www.chromatographyonline.com/view/eluent-preparation-hydrophilic-interaction-liquid-chromatography-part-ii-ph-buffers-and-gradient-elu

In my case after adding more than 25 ml of formic acid to the organic eluent, I used now 10mM NH4Aco in a new experiment. This was immediately pH 6.8. For the organic phase I placed also 770 mg of the salt in 100 ml of water and adjusted the pH with 2 drops of acetic acid and ammonia to also 6.8. This I mixed with 900 ml of ACN. I guess the 10 mM you can specify it on the buffer or on the mixed eluent. However measuring the pH on the organic phase is problematic, because you end up adding so much acid that you come out at 500 mM + instead of the intended 10 mM.

If you have a bonded phase, you would have literally stripped off all the bonded phase. Be careful with the pH! Fortunately, you just had bare silica. They can damage expensive columns.

I will keep this in mind! I just think the description is often quite ambiguous. As I mentioned I switched to the ammonium acetate buffer at ph 6.8 and also adjusted the gradient to 40 or 60 % of strong eluent. I see now, that the product elutes after 14 min instead of 5 min in a gradient of 15 min. I can not say at this moment if this is because if the different buffer or the shallower gradient, but the signal intensity is definitely boosted, even on a less sensitive Instrument.
